# How would you set up Lambda where if a file is uploaded into your S3 bucket, it will copy the files to SFTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sftp

I am trying to see how would you set up Lambda where if a file is uploaded to the S3 bucket, it will copy/push to the SFTP. Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to do, but clearly you can trigger a Lambda function when an object is uploaded to S3, so your Lambda function would read or stream the file down from S3 and then push it out to the SFTP server. Local disk space in the Lambda container is limited (so streaming is a better option) and Lambda runtime is limited to 5 minutes (so the size of file that you'd be able to replicate this way is limited).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! How would you create the function to stream the file and push it to SFTP server? @jarmod

Comment: I would first decide if the limitations on runtime for Lambda are acceptable. Then I would decide what language I wanted to write this code in (you haven't specified one), and then search the web and the relevant AWS SDK docs for how to stream an object from S3 in that programming language. Then I would search for an SFTP package/library for the relevant Lambda runtime environment (node, python, etc.) Then I would write some code. When and if I got stuck, I would consider asking a good question at stackoverflow (per https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).